# NodeJS Mysql pool.query() not releasing connections?

Tags: mysql, node.js, pool, cleardb

I am having trouble with pooling mysql connections with nodeJS. As I understand it, when creating a pool, I should be able to use pool.query() to:

1. Get a connection
2. Run my query
3. Release the connection

However, the issue I am running into is the connections remain open and "sleeps" until the server closes the connection itself (60 seconds). Is there something I am doing wrong here? For context, I am connecting to Heroku clearDB and am viewing the connection on its dashboard.

Example: Upon login, I make a query to check login credentials to authenticate, another query to fetch one set of data, and another query to fetch another set. After logging in, the server is left with 2 connection in "sleep" mode. They do not disconnect until 60 seconds expire.

Here is my db.js file:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const dbConfig = require("./db.config.js");

const connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: dbConfig.HOST,
    user: dbConfig.USER,
    password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
    database: dbConfig.DB,
    port: dbConfig.PORT,
    multipleStatements: true,
    connectionLimit: 10
})

module.exports = connection;
```

Here is how I am making queries:

```
const sql = require("./db.js"); //Our db connection
---OMITTED---
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const select_user = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, username, password, is_admin, is_active FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1"
        const params = [username]
        const user_pass = password

        sql.query(select_user, params, (err, res) => {
            if (res) {
                if (res.length) {
                    const user = res[0]
                    const hash = user.password
                    const is_active = user.is_active
                    if (is_active) {
                        bcrypt.compare(user_pass, hash).then(res => {
                            if (res) {
                                resolve({ result: true, info: { fname: user.first_name, lname: user.last_name, username: user.username, is_admin: user.is_admin, user_id: user.user_id } })
                            } else {
                                reject({ result: false, msg: "wrong_creds" })
                            }
                        }).catch(err => {
                            reject({ result: false, msg: err })

                        })
                    } else {
                        reject({ result: false, msg: "inactive" })
                    }


                } else {
                    reject({ result: false, msg: "user_not_exist" })
                }

            } else {
                console.log("MYSQL QUERY, COULD NOT SELECT USER FOR AUTHENTICATION")
                reject({ result: false, msg: err })
            }
        })


})
```

I'm under the impression that pool.query() will close the connection for me after each query. Is this not the case? Am I missing something once the query has been completed?

I have also tried the manual way:

```
        const select_string = "SELECT * FROM user_backlogs WHERE movie_id = ? AND user_id = ?"
        const params = [movie_id, user_id]
        sql.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else {
                connection.query(select_string, params, (err, res) => {
                    connection.release()
                    if (err) reject(err)
                    else {
                        if (res.length) {
                            resolve([movie_id, "exists", res[0]["added_on"]])
                        } else {
                            resolve([movie_id, "not_exists"])
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

But still, the connections remain up until the server kicks them off. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pool will not close the connection. It will *release* the connection, which me means it can be reused by another query. The pool does this to optimize performance, since it takes time to open a new connection.

If you want to close the connection after use, you can explicitly destroy it  (`connection.destroy()`) and the pool will create a new one the next time you issue a query. You can find more information on this in the documentation under [pooling connections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This pointed me in the right direction.